# How can I intialize a base property that needs an injected service in a Blazor app?

Tags: c#, properties, blazor-server-side

I'll start off by saying I tend to over engineer things.  My environment is Blazor server-side and .Net 6.

I have 3 app roles I use for authorization.  The role assignments are handled in the Azure app service and passed to my application in the manifest.  During the login, I read them out with `user.IsInRole(<role name>)` and save them to the `ProtectedSessionStorage`.  They are used in virtually every component to enable/disable functionality based on the user's role.

I created a base class, that every class inherits, to manage basic access i.e. `[Authorize(Roles = "Approver, Owner")]`.  To get the roles for component access I started retrieving it from storage `var isApprover = (await Storage.GetAsync<bool>("IsApprover")).Value;`

I've believe that the storage source should be invisible.  In other words, the developer shouldn't have to know if the info is in session storage, or Redis, or anywhere else.  They should just have access to a property "IsApprover", "IsOwner", etc.  That way the storage can be changed and you don't have to update a dozen different places.

I'm trying to get the storage value in the base class.  I tried putting it in the constructor

```
public BasePage()
{
    IsApprover = Storage.GetAsync<bool>("IsApprover").Result.Value;
}
```

but `ProtectedSessionStorage` is injected so its not available yet.

I tried doing it in `OnInitialized`

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    IsApprover = (await Storage.GetAsync<bool>("IsApprover")).Value;
}
```

but I can't call OnInitialized in every child class and that also defeats my goal of just having the property.

I also tried the property `setter` in the base class

```
private bool _ta { get; set; }
public bool IsTaxApprover {
    get { return _ta; }
    set {
        _ta = Storage.GetAsync<bool>("IsTaxApprover").Result.Value;
    }
}
```

but it appears to never set the value.  I check the value on my Index page which inherits the Base

```
if (IsTaxApprover)
    <do stuff here...>
else
    <do stuff here...>
```

but the value is never set.

I appreciate any assistance you can give.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but..  On the assumption you are logging in on each SPA session, why not just store the values in a scoped service?

Comment: No, its me that missing something.  I wasn't aware of that.  I mean, I know what a scoped service is but saving to one is new for me.  I'll start reading up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MrC aka Shaun Curtis for pointing me in the right direction.

I found out I can create a service with an interface that exposes properties.  To get started I created two properties.

```
public interface IAuthorizationService
{
    bool IsApprover { get; }
    bool IsOwner { get; }
}
```

Then in the class I'm populating the properties from the Authentication Service.

```
public class AuthorizationService : IAuthorizationService
{   
    private AuthenticationState AuthState { get; set; }
    bool _isOwner;
    bool IAuthorizationService.IsOwner { 
        get => _isOwner; }
    bool _isApprover;
    bool IAuthorizationService.IsApprover { 
        get => _isApprover; }

    public AuthorizationService(AuthenticationStateProvider authState) {

        AuthState = authState.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
        var user = AuthState.User;
        _isOwner = user.IsInRole("TaxonomyOwner");
        _isApprover = user.IsInRole("TaxonomyApprover");
    }

}
```

If you use DI, this has to be registered in your Program.CS like any other service.  I then inject it in the constructor and the properties are available.  For example, in my Index page, I check authorization in `OnInitialization`

```
if (AuthService.IsApprover == true)
    result = await RequestDomain.GetAllRequestsAsync(ChangePeriod.ChangePeriodId).ConfigureAwait(false);
else
    result = await RequestDomain.GetRequestsAsync(UserEmail ?? "").ConfigureAwait(false);
```